# How to prevent one section overlapping the other

Tags: html, css

What I have seems to be a simple issue but I cant just wrap my head around it. I have googled around but all fixes for similar questions didn't help, which is why I'm asking for help here.

I am building a landing page with several sections stacked on each other. Each section is set to occupy the full height of the view port, and all except one is set to take up 100% width of the screen too.

However, when I reduce the screen height, the sections overlap each other. I have tried to set the overflow of each section to hidden, I still get the same behaviour. What I want is that each section be of fixed height as the browser height reduces and not get pushed into the upper section. Below is the snippet of my code.

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.introd{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3rem 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="introd">
    <div class="introd_wrapper">
        <h2 class="text-center">Introduction</h2>
        <div class="contents">
            some contents here
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you add some html to make it a working snippet of the actual problem you're facing? So we can help you better.

Comment: @ElusiveCoder i have added html, thanks.

Comment: @Flexi Change `<section="introd">` to `<section class="introd">`. There's no class attribute.

Comment: I am not able to see any overlapping section..

Comment: @Flexi Do you mean the horizontal scrollbar shows up?

Comment: @Flexi Is it the horizontal scrollbar that bothers you?

Comment: @jstarnate no horizontal scrollbars..as i reduce the screen height the contents of the section below gets pushed into the section above and so on

Comment: I tried your example. No overlapping happened

Comment: @Flexi Did you reset `body, section` default margin to 0.

Comment: Nobody here seems to be able to reproduce your issue, or understand what you are actually talking about. So please provide a proper [mcve], that fully reproduces the issue.

Comment: I just observed that when i remove the height and width of each section, the overlapping stops. But there's a problem now, the height of each section should be the height of the view port but it isn't

Comment: @MoorthyG yes i did

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the padding of `.section` elements. To avoid the padding being added up to an element's width and height, set its `box-sizing` property to `border-box` like so:

```
.section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3rem 4rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, you don't need to style the body just to make the elements stretch because each already has a width and height set.

Comment: Thanks @jstarnate..i have set box-sizing on each section, the behaviour remains the same.